# apple pay button not showing

Tags: flutter, applepay

Im using [pay](https://pub.dev/packages/pay) package to intergrate apple pay in my app and its showing pay button in simulator but not in real device

I have

1. logged out apple account from the device
2. created a new google account and added it as test account in apple developer console under sandbox
3. logged into that testing account on device(setting device location and billing address to US since sandboxing doesn't work in my Country)
4. added test cards in device.

But still the button is not getting visible.

Comment: Solved!!! Forgot to add apple pay capability in Xcode